# i want to get first cell of excel sheet and iterate the column

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

[image: Here is the image of my excel sheet]

I want to start from first cell and then iterate the Line column if number is found in Line column then return the number and if not then continue the for loop to the last record.Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have done so far? stackoverflow is not a code writing service..

Comment: We know how tables look like. Your screenshot is pointless. You want to post your **code** as [mcve]; with a clear description what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly get the 1st cell of excel and then you iterate the whole column of that sheet for example ,

```
String a="A";
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(a+0);
Row row = xssfSheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
```

Now you get the `AO` cell of sheet that is first cell of the sheet , now from that cell you can iterate the whole column like below ,

```
    String a="A";
    for (int i = 0; i < xssfSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++)
{
  CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(a+i);
    Row row = xssfSheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());

        //your Logic
}
```

I thought this is what you want exactly , let me know if you want any other help, Thank you.